# Can a topshelf hosted app on the commandline detect key-presses?

Tags: .net, topshelf

When a Topshelf hosted app runs on a console, not as service, you stop it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. That is handled by Topshelf for you (wrapping the `CancelKeyPress` of `Console`). Is it possible to register a handler for other keys with Topshelf so that I might control some small details of my service when the key <kbd>m</kbd> is pressed or maybe <kbd>F5</kbd> (all while the console window has focus of course and all not available when running as a service)?

Comment: Have you tried registering the handler in the Startup method of your Constructing class for Topshelf?

Comment: @ColinM Which handler? The only thing beside my service instance I can have in the `Startup` method is the Topshelf `HostControl` which does not offer an events. Also the `Console` class itself only has a `CancelKeyPress` event. Nothing to get any keypress while the service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services are not generally designed to support interactive control, so there is no way to do this with Topshelf. If you need to control your service, the use of a separate mechanism is recommended, such as a socket (either raw, or via HTTP self-hosted, etc.) or message-based communication to the service.

Comment: I see the point in that and I was just thinking about providing some debug feature while running as a console application rather than a service. But it would also mean that both modes would no longer equal each other in functionality so I will go the way with a control communication protocol from another tool. Thanks.